# how to upload file in a specific address using django admin panel?

Tags: python, django, django-admin, wamp, backend

I'm Developing a django admin panel that has image upload capability ,image upload works successfully ,  but i cant access to images from entering urls in browser .

When I want to try to access to a picture like this :

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/485508.jpg
```

I get this error :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/485508.jpg
```

Here Is My Codes :

Models.py :

```
picurl = models.ImageField()
```

Settings.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/'
if not os.path.exists(MEDIA_ROOT):
    os.makedirs(MEDIA_ROOT)
```

and i can see the file in the specified folder successfully uploaded .

How can i access to pictures in the url ?
and How Can I upload files to Wamp WWW Folder ? 
any suggestions will be helpfull  .
thanks .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main `urls.py` add pattern for them like below.

**urls.py**

```
...
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
...

urlpatterns = [
    ...
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**settings**

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```