# how to show an image in the django templates dynamically?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to show the uploaded image in the django templates,but it was not showing any image,i have successfully uploaded and saved it,how can i fix this problem,could anyone please explain or a sample demo on how we have to configure our settings.py to display the image in templates?

my settings.py:

```
LOGIN_URL='/login'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/home'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL='/accounts'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

my models.py:

```
class Images(models.Model):
    user_id=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    image=models.FileField(upload_to='home')
```

And the Image tag i was using to display it is

```
<img src="{{ obj.image.url }}" class="img-circle" height="65" width="65" alt="Avatar">
```

my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from . models import FavBooks
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
app_name='home'

    urlpatterns=[
        path('',views.HomeView,name='home'),
        path('addBooks/',views.addBooks,name='addBooks'),
        path('uploadpic/',views.uploadPic,name='uploadPic'),
        path('myBooks/',views.BooksView.as_view(),name='myBooks'),
        path('<int:pk>/', views.BookDetailsView.as_view(), name='myBooks'),
        path('search/', views.SearchedBooks, name='searchedBooks'),
        path('favoriteAjax/', views.favorite_ajax, name='favoriteAjax'),
        path('removefavoriteAjax/', views.removefavorite_ajax, name='removefavoriteAjax'),
        path('wishList/',views.WishlistView.as_view(),name='wishList'),
        path('deletebook/', views.deleteBook, name='deleteBook'),
        ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54686372/5840704

Comment: I have added that to my urls.py but still it was not showing any image

Comment: Show your main urls.py

Comment: i have added it to my question please take a look

Comment: Are you sure that this is the main urls.py. I think this is the urls.py for one of django apps.

Comment: yeah added but it is  not showing any image

Comment: I’m talking about myproject/urls.py not home/urls.py. You should put it into myproject/urls.py.

Comment: Sorry That was my mistake i have actually added that to apps/urls.py ,thank you so much i got it now!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add this in urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```